# How to add a recaptcha to magento 1 newsletter form

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, newsletter

I'm trying to add recaptcha to the default magento 1.9 subscribe.phtml file. I've added the JS via the misc scripts in the administration, and I've added the site key to the form, however it's not picking it up.

Is this because of the VarianForm validation?

How would I get recaptcha to work with the newsletter subscription form?

```
<div id="subscribe-form" class="clearer">
<form action="/newsletter/subscriber/new/" method="post">
    <div>
        <div class="newsletterInputArea">
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Join') ?>" class="button btn-inline"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Join') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY HERE"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you can customize https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html